# what video/image encoding format is recommended when trying to encode and transmit raw video in real time?

Tags: c++, c, compression, real-time, video-encoding

I'm trying to encode and transfer raw video frames over LAN (100 Mbps) connection (frames captured by a web cam). What video/image encoding format is recommended for fast compression (with not much regard for the compression ratio) ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need individual frames to be independent of one another, use mjpeg (which is equivalent to encoding each frame as a jpeg). It's simple and you have plenty of tools with which to manipulate it.

Otherwise, as long as you have a remotely modern cpu and the resolution isn't insanely high, just use a simple mpeg4 asp or even h264 profile. Encoding 320x240 video with the simplest profile should take less than 5% cpu on a current low-end machine.

Comment: Thanks R. Unfortunately mjpeg/jpeg compression seem to result in lower framerate . Encoding each frame as PNG seem to move the rate upto 11 fps. Still looking for ways to compress faster :(.

Comment: Something's wrong if it's taking that long. Which library are you using to do the compression?

Comment: Hi R. I'm using the Gdiplus (Image class) for quick conversion between pixel data to other formats. It can hardly perform 3 jpeg conversions/sec (for a 1024x768 size frame with true color).

Comment: Then this is your problem. Inefficient libs like that might work for 160x120 or maybe even 320x240, but for high resolution you really need to switch to `libavcodec`. One way you can tell your library is bad is that it's slower than compressing as png! Any good jpeg implementation should encode at least a few times (if not orders of magnitude) faster than png.